# Java and naming of method to get enum from int

Tags: java, enums, type-conversion

I have an enum, where each enum maps to an integer, which doesn't match with enum's `ordinal()`. And now I need a method to convert integer to enum. I think have two options:

1. A new method with unique name, such as (idiomatic?):

   ```
   public static MyEnum fromInt(int i) {}
   ```
2. Overload of `valueOf()`:

   ```
   public static MyEnum valueOf(int i) {}
   ```

Are both ok, or is one of them clearly bad or good?

Would it be good or bad to provide *both*? If yes, should they be identical or behave subtly differently, such as behave differently if `i` is not valid value.

Or is there some 3rd option which is superior to both of these?

I'm looking for a short answer telling how this should be done to conform to *established Java coding practices*. The enum will be used by others and maintained for a long time. Please answer with some kind of authoritative reference, or strong experience, not purely opinion or feeling of what is better.

Also, this question is not about how to implement this method, it's only about how it should be named, and if the name depends on exact behaviour, to be most consistent with rest of the "Java world".

Comment: Don't overload valueOf() - It will confuse humans. The factory method is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opinion first:

I normally name my enum factory methods based on its purpose, not just valueOf or anything.
For example consider, hypothetically:

```
public enum Language{
 GERMAN(345),
 ENGLISH(342);

 private int isoCode;

 public static Language fromIsoCode(int isoCode){
  //do my logic here
 }
}
```

In this case, i am telling my library users exactly what should be passed to fromIsoCode, the isocode, not ordinal, or any other integer that may be part of the enum.

So to suggest, reconsider naming fromInt or valueOf, and name it based on what that integer really represent in the context of the enum.

Answer (score 6):

Presumably the number *means* something - so I'd create a method which uses that information. For example:

```
public enum HttpStatus {
    OK(200),
    ...
    NOT_FOUND(404);

    private int statusCode;

    private HttpStatus(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public static HttpStatus fromStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Just `fromInt` doesn't give any indication of the expected *meaning* of the integer... and it also doesn't allow for alternative `int`-based lookup later.

Comment: @maress, surely Jon Skeet types fast. This is Jon Skeet Himself! :)

Answer (score 3):

I personally dislike `fromInt()` because its name does not add anything to reader to understand what does this method do. `valueOf()` name does not contain additional information to, but looks more familiar.

However if your `int` has some name, e.g. `id`, I'd probably prefer method `fromId()`.